# Providing Dynamic Dates in log4j2

Tags: log4j2

For a multi threaded environment if i am loading the configurations only once , then the next day how should i pass the date programmatically so that logs will be written in directory as that days date.

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Which appenders are you referring to? The rolling file appender, the file appender?

Comment: i am using rolling file appender

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html#DateLookup has an example of how to do it.